# How to change wxpython direction?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# simple.py

import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Simple application')
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

but when I get output my direction is RTL.How can I change frame direction to ltr?
[image]

Comment: How are the other programs you run? I believe this is not directly connected to wxPython, you must set it in your Windows.

Comment: I found below solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After on day test,I found this code:

```
class DefaultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Default Frame", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_LeftToRight)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    django_init()
    app = wx.App()
    frame = DefaultFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And result is below:

[image]